# Process.getErrorStream doesn't capture all errors

Tags: java

I use ProcessBuilder to create a Process that runs a script on Linux. I need to check if there were errors while executing this script.

```
public static String contentInStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException
{
    return contentInReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
}

public static String contentInReader(Reader reader) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line;
    String content = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        content += line+"\n";
    }
    return content;
}

public static void execScript(String script)
{
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh", script);
    Process process = pb.start();
    process.waitFor();
    String errors = contentInStream(process.getErrorStream());
    if (!errors.isEmpty())
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(errors);
    }
}
```

In a test script I produce two errors, one by explicitly writing to the error channel, and one by trying to write to a file where the script doesn't have write rights.

```
echo Warning
date > in
>&2 echo Error
```

The problem is that the string errors only contains "Error", not the error from the command "date > in". The file "in" is not created, as expected. If I try "./testScript.sh > /tmp/std 2> /tmp/err", both errors are in /tmp/err, as expected.

String errors contains: `Error`

Output when script is run by itself:
`/apps/testScript.sh: line 2: in: Permission denied
Error`

PS: I also tested with the order of the two last lines in the test script reversed. I got the same result, so the error is probably not in contentInReader.

Comment: Have you tried making `script` be the only argument to ProcessBuilder? Having the first argument be `sh` is redundent since `pb.start()` calls `sh -c`.

Comment: @walsht : you're right, but removing the sh doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You're doing this wrong. You need to capture both the output and the error streams, and you need to do so *before* calling `waitFor()`. Otherwise the process can get jammed producing output. You should either start two threads, one for each of those streams, and wait for them to finish, or merge the output and error streams and use your present code, and *then* call `waitFor()`.

Comment: @EJP: I found this out myself when looking for a solution. However, the output of the script is guaranteed to be short, so it will not be an issue. Merging the output and error streams is not an option, because if there are errors I have to throw an exception. If I don't know if the output is an error, I can't decide if I have to throw an exception.

Comment: If there's an error the script should return a non-zero value, which you can get via `exitStatus()`.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it. Apparently the script was executing in a different directory when it was started from the Java process, where the script has write permissions. So there was no error, and getErrorStream did capture all error output, in this case just "Error".